# Calling a web service from a scheduled task in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I am working on a scheduled task in Kentico and I need the task to call methods that exist in a separate web service. I'd like to know if it's possible or not and how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

When connecting and interacting with web services there are no extraordinary steps that you have to take. There is a sample service present in  CMSPages/WebService.asmx. that you can use as a reference to creating your own web service and you are free to add your own "asmx" handlers as you would to any other .NET application. Kentico is in the end a standard .NET application and you can create those without any problems.

Additionally I would recommend to using Web API 2.0 instead of the old asmx handlers. In order to see how you can create such web service you can check [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Using+ASP.NET+Web+API+with+Kentico#UsingASP.NETWebAPIwithKentico-UsingASP.NETWebAPI2) which contains an example.